# Folland 9.10: Smoothness of Convolutions of Tempered Distributions and Schwartz Functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

We define the following symbols:

- $D = D(\mathbb{R}^n) = C_c^\infty$, the space of test functions from $\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{C}$, equipped with the standard $C_c^\infty$ topology.
- $D(U) = $ the space of test functions whose support is contained in $U$ as a subset,
- $D'(U) = $ the space of distributions (continuous linear functionals) on $D(U)$, equipped with the weak-* topology,
- $S = $ Schwartz Space, equipped with the semi-norms $\lVert{\cdot}\rVert_{(N,\alpha)}$, where

$$
\lVert{ f}\rVert_{(N,\alpha)} = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} (1+\vert x\vert)^N\vert\partial^\alpha f(x)\vert
$$

where $\vert\cdot\vert$ is the standard Euclidean norm.

- $S' = $ the space of Tempered Distributions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, equipped with the weak-* topology.

The text I am following is Folland's Real Analysis. [Errata here](https://sites.math.washington.edu//%7Efolland/Homepage/reals.pdf)

I am trying to prove that the convolution between $F\in S'$ and $\psi\in S$ produces a $C^\infty$ function. Where

$$
(F\ast \psi)(x) = \langle F, \tau_x \widetilde{\psi}\rangle,\quad\text{where}\quad (\tau_x \widetilde{\psi})(y) = \psi(x-y)
$$

Excerpt of the Proposition below:
[image]
[image]

Proposition 9.9 concerns Density of $C_c^\infty$ in $S$, and the relevant parts of 9.3 are below

[image]

If we attempt the same technique as in 9.3, we get

$$\lim_{t\to 0}t^{-1}\biggl[(F\ast\psi)(x+te_j) - (F\ast\psi)(x)\biggr]=\lim_{t\to 0}\biggl\langle F, \: t^{-1}[\tau_{x+te_j}\widetilde{\psi} - \tau_{x}\widetilde{\psi}]\biggr\rangle$$

I do not see how we can push the limit inside the bracket, because we would require the difference quotient to converge in $S$ to the partial of $\phi$,

$$
t^{-1}\biggl[\tau_{x+te_j}\widetilde{\psi} - \tau_{x}\widetilde{\psi}\biggr](y)\overbrace{\longrightarrow}^{\text{in }S}\tau_x\widetilde{\partial/\partial x^j \psi}(y)\quad \text{as }t\to 0
$$

I have proven:

- If $f\in S$, then $f$ vanishes at infinity, which implies $f$ is uniformly continuous,
- If $f\in S$, so are all its derivatives $\partial^\alpha f\in S$ for every multi-index $\alpha$,

How do we show

$$
\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}(1+\vert y\vert)^N\Biggl[\dfrac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial y}\biggl(\dfrac{\psi(x+t e_j - y) - \psi(x - y)}{t} - \dfrac{\partial \psi(y)}{\partial x^j}\biggr)\Biggr]\to 0
$$

I also attempted an alternative line of argumentation, by borrowing properties of the convolution on $C_c^\infty$, but we require the uniform convergence of $\partial^\alpha(F\ast \psi_j)$. Let $\{\psi_j\}_{j\geq 1}\subseteq D(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a sequence converging to $\psi$ in $S$. The restriction of the tempered distribution onto $D$ is a distribution, therefore

$$
(\partial^\alpha(F\ast \psi_j))(x) = (F\ast (\partial^\alpha \psi_j))(x) = \biggl\langle F, \: \tau_x\widetilde{\partial^\alpha\psi_j}\biggr\rangle
$$

The sequence $\{\tau_x\widetilde{\partial^\alpha \psi_j}\}\subseteq D(\mathbb{R}^n)$ converges in $S$ to $\tau_x\widetilde{\partial^\alpha \psi}$ which is almost what we want, but we still cannot claim

$$
\lim \partial^\alpha (F\ast \psi_j)(x) = \partial^\alpha \lim (F\ast\psi_j)(x)
$$

Since $F$ is endowed with the weak-* topology, I don't see where we can get this 'uniformity' in convergence.

Comment: May be Lagrange intermediate value theorem will help you in some critical step. Best wishes. If you want more knowledge about this, you can refer to the homepage of Dyatlov MIT or see the book of GTM252《Distributions and operators》. Your question concerning a lot of details  , so I just give you some reference.